# Windows 10 Wifi Adapter missing, and Airplane mode is greyed out

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, laptop, airplane-mode

I have a windows 10 laptop Hp Envy X360 Convertible 15m-ed1xxx

After charging it last night we went to use the wifi and it looked like airplane mode was greyed out and the wifi adapter wasn't showing any connections

Went to control panel > Network and Sharing Center and noticed my wifi adapter isn't there?.

Went to Device manager and didn't see it there also. Went to View > show all hidden devices. Then i saw my adapter it was greyed out. uninstalled it since after you reboot it shows up and installs itself.

Reboot, No wifi adapter showing any connections

Went to another laptop and downloaded the correct drivers for the specific laptop installed rebooted and still no adapter.

Last resort I reinstalled windows while keeping files. let it run came back the next morning and still the airplane mode is on and there is no wifi adapter.

I don't know what else to do.

As far as airplane mode i've pressed the fn key and all F1-f12 keys with no resolution. I've tried the fn key with PrtScrn and whatever else I saw on the laptop keyboard with nothing happening

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Sounds like your wifi adapter has a problem, perhaps because of a power glitch during the night. Is your computer protected by a surge-protector or a UPS? Or was there a Windows Update done at night?

Comment: @harrymc Will a full reinstall of windows 10 do the trick? The last one was reinstall while preserving everything

Comment: I don't believe so. Buying an external USB wifi adapter will be much cheaper than repairing the computer.

Comment: Unless you user profile is damaged, Keep Everything will normally work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Went to Device manager and didn't see it there also. ......  show all
> hidden devices. Then i saw my adapter it was greyed out.

The Network Adapter device shows up in regular device manager. It is not a hidden device. That is some other (likely virtual) adapter.

Your wireless network card has a hardware error and needs to be replaced.  That you reinstalled Windows and it still did not work is added evidence that the card has a hardware error.

Get a local shop to do this if opening your laptop is too daunting.

Replacing the adapter is normally a good idea because that is internal to the machine.

You can try a USB adapter, but then that has to be carried around with you.

Also, you did a Repair Install.  If you believe your profile or other damage occurred, back up and do a fresh install to see if that works.

Device manager does suggest a hardware issue.

Comment: Before taking to a shop, 1. Look for loose connections to network card (See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgiBiM7_UHE at ~7:35) . 2. It would be far less expensive to buy a USB-WiFi adapter (US$10 and up), and it might even improve throughput, rather than to fix a damaged internal adapter.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I know a good repair shop that is not that far from my house they have been working on our laptops whenever they have issues (hardware) they always give me a good price's

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I'm gonna try safe mode to see if it works. what do i do if it works in safe mode? do i create a new profile and use it then delete the old one? i'm currently backing up everything

Comment: Let us know about Safe Mode.  If the profile is not working, a fresh install is best. I did further clarify my answer

Comment: @John I'm trying to go into safe mode but its saying that there is a bitlocker key for the os. how do i get this key so i can go into safe mode?

Comment: You need the bitlocker key - you should have that.

Comment: You can start the machine without WiFi - you imply this in your question. Back off all important information to a USB drive. Be ready to format and do a completely fresh install of Windows.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I bought a dongle and connected now. will use it for now and send my laptop in for repair at a later date. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: So your adapter has failed.  I also suggested in my answer that you try a USB adapter. So I think my answer covers all the bases

Comment: Thanks @John yep you were right. I got a dongle from amazon TP-link that was overnighted. it worked but kept disconnecting. so went to Best Buy and got a Net gear dual band and it's working fine. its temporary till we get the actually network card replaced. wife needs it right now

Comment: You should perhaps acknowledge my answer in this case

Comment: Thanks @John get that rep :P